# What to do when function calls a dynamically created element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have tried reading up on my problem and gather event delegation and/or event listeners seem like what I need to do. However, I am confused on the implementation for my script so help would be appreciated.

I can see the problem is probably that the showSlides function references mySlides and grid-box which are dynamically created elements that have not yet been created when the function is called. Is that right? It is a slideshow viewer for context which worked when I did not dynamically create the elements.

The top section is when I did not make the HTML elements dynamically and it worked.

```js
    var num_slides = 3
     
    for (let i=1; i<num_slides; i++) {
     
    var $my_slides= $("<div><img style = 'width:100%'/></div>", {"class": "mySlides"});
    $('#slideshow-container').prepend($my_slides);
     
    var $grid_box = $("<div><img/></div>", {"class": "grid-box"});
    //  $(document).on('click','div.grid-box',currentSlide(i));    ​// I've tried this
    $grid_box.on('click', function(event){currentSlide(i)}); 
    $('#picture-grid').append($grid_box);
     
    }
     
    function showSlides(n) {
      var i;
      var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
      var gridboxes = document.getElementsByClassName("grid-box");
      if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
      if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
      for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
          slides[i].style.display = "none";  
      }
     
      for (i = 0; i < gridboxes.length; i++) {
        gridboxes[i].classList.remove("active");
      }
      slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
      gridboxes[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
    }
     
    var slideIndex = 1;
    showSlides(slideIndex);
     
    function plusSlides(n) {
      showSlides(slideIndex += n);
    }
     
    function currentSlide(n) {
      showSlides(slideIndex = n);
    }

document.onkeydown = function(event) {switch (event.keyCode) {case 37:currentSlide(slideIndex-1);break;case 39:currentSlide(slideIndex+1);break;}};
     
    function onChangeMap(){
     
      const met_var = this.value;
      const basepath = '/home/2015_casestudy/';
      var startYear = 2014;
      var startMon = 1;
     
      document.querySelectorAll('.mySlides img').forEach(function(img, index){
     
        if ((startMon + index) % 12 == 0) {
          monthNum = 12;
          yearNum = startYear + ((startMon+index) / 12) - 1;
        } else {
          monthNum = (startMon+index) % 12
          yearNum = Math.floor(startYear + ((startMon+index) / 12));
        }
     
        var formattedMonthNum = ("0" + monthNum.toString()).slice(-2);
     
        var dateTag = yearNum.toString() + formattedMonthNum
     
        if ((met_var == 'sm_anom_1month' || met_var == 'sm_pct_1month') && (yearNum == 2014)) {
        img.src = basepath + "blank.png";
        } else {
        img.src = basepath + met_var + '_' + dateTag + "?" + new Date().getTime();}
      })
     
      document.querySelectorAll('.picture-grid img').forEach(function(img, index){
     
        if ((startMon + index) % 12 == 0) {
          monthNum = 12;
          yearNum = startYear + ((startMon+index) / 12) - 1;
        } else {
          monthNum = (startMon+index) % 12
          yearNum = Math.floor(startYear + ((startMon+index) / 12));
        }
     
        var formattedMonthNum = ("0" + monthNum.toString()).slice(-2);
     
        var dateTag = yearNum.toString() + formattedMonthNum
     
        if ((met_var == 'sm_anom_1month' || met_var == 'sm_pct_1month') && (yearNum == 2014)) {
          img.src = basepath + "blank.png";
        } else {
          img.src = basepath + met_var + '_' + dateTag +  "?" + new Date().getTime();}
        })
      }
     
    window.addEventListener("load",
    initPage);
     
    function initPage(){
    document.querySelector('#myFormSelect').addEventListener("change", onChangeMap);
    document.querySelector('#myFormSelect').dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
    }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js" 
        type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

<select id="myFormSelect" name="met variables">
<option value="temp" selected='selected'>Temp</option>
<option value="rain">Rainfall</option>
</select>
    
    <div id="slideshow-container" class="slideshow-container">
      <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
    </div>
    
    <div id="picture-grid" class="picture-grid"></div>
```

Comment: What is the expected behavior?  Please clarify.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @James The error is 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined 
at showSlides (slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";),
at slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";

Comment: @DominiqueFortin expected behavior is that when I click the grid-box pictures, then the slide changes to the picture in the grid box. I'll post up the rest of the code.

Comment: Why do you hide all the slides, you only need to hide the visible one before showing the clicked one?

Comment: Also since your using JQuery, why do you do `gridboxes[slideIndex-1].className += " active"` and not `$(gridboxes[slideIndex-1]).addClass("active")`.  `document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides")` would become `$('.mySlides')`.

Comment: @DominiqueFortin I started off without JQuery but only started using it when I tried to make the elements dynamically. I wanted to use 48 pictures and I could get it to work by repeating the static creation 48 times but I wanted to use dynamic creation to make it neater.

Regarding why I hid all the slides, I just decided to go with this way of making the viewer. Where all the pictures are there, but they are hidden except for one - the one that is clicked.

Comment: @AzureWinds You still only need to hide the visible one before showing the clicked one.

Comment: To find the cause of the error do `try { ... code to check ... } catch(e) { debugger; }`. Then inspect the variable's content.

Comment: @DominiqueFortin Ok I did the JQuery edits, thank you. I'm not sure how to implement hiding only the visible one, can I do that later? I gather the dynamically created elements is a separate problem? I am very new to JS/Jquery.

Comment: @DominiqueFortin I put my entire code into the try block, where does the output show?

Comment: @AzureWinds Use chrome.  In the menu, choose More Tools then Developer Tools.  In Dev Tools click on the Source tab and refresh your page.  When the error occurs, you'll see the line where `debugger;` is in Dev Tools and you'll be able to debug.

Comment: @DominiqueFortin Thanks for replying, sorry for my delay in response. I have put in the code into the debugger, it says -

Comment: @DominiqueFortin 

TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
    at showSlides (/carousel_test.html:168:24)
    at /carousel_test.html:185:1

168: slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
185: showSlides(slideIndex);

I suspect it is because the Javascript is calling a dynamically created div that hasn't been created yet. But I don't know how to do the loading so the Javascript is called after the divs are created.

Comment: @AzureWinds Where is `#myFormSelect`.

Comment: @DominiqueFortin #myFormSelect is to change part of the img src so that I can select different type of images based onwhat is selected in the form. E.g.
`
<select id="myFormSelect" name="met variables">
    <option value="rain_3month">Rain</option>
    <option value="temp_1month">Temp</option>

  </select> `

Comment: @AzureWinds If you click on run code snippet, you can see the error.  Can you add what missing in your example above.

Comment: @DominiqueFortin Thanks for your help, I see it running. I've added in the extra code. I can see this being a test, but since there is not picture source, how will it work? The error in the snippet is the error I get on my site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you are created the 's might be running at the same time as the code you have.

Make sure they are created before the code you have. Also, appears that the code is referring to div's with a specific class.
When you are creating the divs in a loop, don't forget to add the appropriate class to match what the code is trying to find.

The code is unable to find the div's either because they are created at the wrong time, or they just don't have the correct id/class names.

```
    var $grid_box = $("<div><img/></div>", {"class": "grid-box"});
```

Here was your working version: with the missing class name +.correct onClick calls inside the append

```
    var $grid_box = $("<div class='grid-box' onclick='javascript:currentSlide(' + i + ')'><img/></div>');
```